# Is it true that a mapping between metric spaces is continuous iff the image of every open set is open?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Just want to change Rudin theorem 4.8 a bit and see if this works.

The original theorem  is ... $f$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}(V) $ is open in $X$ for every open set $V$ in $Y$.

If I  change  the inverse image to image, is this still true?

Comment: Do you mean the criterion in your title, as opposed to Rudin's formulation?

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: @BolzWeir edited

Comment: @Bernard Yes you're right

Comment: I knew what you were asking about before the edit. It isn't true in general.

Comment: So what's the problem here? Can you briefly explain? @BolzWeir

Comment: See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75589/open-maps-which-are-not-continuous

Answer (score 1):

A function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$ for any open set $V\subset Y$.
(This is sometimes taken to be the definition.)
A function $f:X\to Y$ is open if and only if $f(V)$ is open in $Y$ for any open set $V\subset X$.
(This is the definition.)
These two are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is false. The property you mention for $f$ is called an *open map*:

(i) An open map can be non-continuous: suppose $Y$ is a discrete topological space. Then any map from $X$ to $Y$ is open, but can be non-continuous.

(ii) A continuous map is not necessarily open: if $Y$ is a non-open subset of $X$, with the induced topology, the canonical injection of $$ in $X$ is continuous, by definition of the induced topology, but the image of $Y$ is not open.

Comment: So for R^k would the result be changed?

Comment: @maj $f(x)=x^2$ is a continuous map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. It is not open.