# Example of an open set that is discontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Can anyone give me an example of a function $f: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ such that for any open subset $V$ in $\Bbb R$, $f(V)$ is open but $f$ is not continuous at any point.

This was a side comment my professor made and I haven't been able to quite wrap my head around this yet.

Comment: you can see this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75589/open-maps-which-are-not-continuous and compose with an homeomorphism between $\Bbb R$ and $(0,1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [Conway base 13 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function). The image of any open set is the entire real line, but...