# A notion reverse to continuity, does it have a name?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, terminology

Does the following notion (in some sense reverse to continuity) have a name? What are interesting properties of this concept?

$f$ is "anticontinuous" in $x$ if $$\forall \epsilon>0 \exists \delta>0:f[(x-\epsilon;x+\epsilon)]\supseteq (f(x)-\delta;f(x)+\delta).$$

(Here $f[X]$ is the image of a set $X$ under a map $f$.)

Comment: If that holds for all $x$, then $f$ is called an *open map*.

Comment: Piggy-backing on @Berci see the Wikipedia article for [Open and closed maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps). See also [Intuition for an open mapping](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/674991/13130) *AND* [Questions concerning properties of open and closed maps in general topological spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3353579/13130) *AND* [Open maps which are not continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/75589/13130) *AND* [Alternate topological definition of continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2100699/13130).

Answer (score 3):

As Berci commented, when we demand that this hold for all $x$ in the domain of the function we're just saying that $f$ maps open sets to open sets - this is the definition of an **open map**. Similarly, a **closed map** is a map sending closed sets to closed sets. Closedness, openness, and continuity are fundamentally independent:

- If $X$ has more than one element, the identity map on $X$ is closed and open but not continuous when we equip the domain with the indiscrete topology and the codomain with the discrete topology.
- The "left inclusion" map $$\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2:a\mapsto (a,0)$$ (with the usual topologies on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$) is closed and continuous but not open.
- The "left projection" map $$\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}: (a,b)\mapsto a$$ is continuous and open but not closed.

It's a good exercise to check each of these examples.

*(Meanwhile, the obvious fourth notion - "preimages of closed sets are closed" - is equivalent to continuity, since the complement of the preimage is the preimage of the complement)*.

I've seen in conversation the term "open *at $x$*" used to refer to the situation you describe, but I haven't seen that in a formal text so I don't know if it's universally accepted.