# Question on the open set characterization of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I know the theorem ---

> Let $(X, d)$ and $(X', d')$ be metric spaces. $f: X \mapsto X'$ is a continuous
>   function if and only if for every open set $U \subset X'$, $f^{-1}(U)\subset X$ is open in X.

Does that mean for every open set $A \subset X$, $f(A) \subset X'$ is open? Basically, I'm asking whether the part that comes after "if and only if" works conversely?

Comment: You missed an "open" before $U\subset X'$ in the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The maps with the property that $f(A)\subset X'$ is open whenever $A\subset X$ is open are called open maps. Not all open maps are continuous. See here: [Open maps which are not continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75589/open-maps-which-are-not-continuous)

Conversely, each constant map is continuous, but clearly not open.