# How to construct examples of maps that are open or closed or continuous but not the others?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, examples-counterexamples

I came across this exercise, the main problem for me are the restrictions, i need to find examples for maps $f: \mathbb {R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb {R}^2$ or subsets of them such that $f$ is only one or two of the three at the same time. (I.e $f$ is open but no closed nor continuous)
But i don't know How to build such examples, as i also don't see the kind of patologies i should be looking for

Comment: Do you know any of them?

Comment: On open mappings that are not continuous: "Explicit examples are moderately difficult to construct, but it’s not too hard to come up with non-constructive examples; here’s one such [...]" https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75589/open-maps-which-are-not-continuous

Comment: @MoisheCohen There is an important difference as that question asks for $f:X\to Y$ where $X,Y\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ while this question requires $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @SmileyCraft: True, but two out of three examples given there are defined on $R^2$ and the remaining example of continuous but not closed is only superficially defined on a smaller subset since the open disk is homeomorphic to $R^2$.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Well I have been looking around on the internet and I honestly can not find any open closed function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ that is not continuous. I have found an open function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ that is not continuous, or rather LoveTooNap29 did, but it is not closed. All the other 6 combinations of open, closed and continuous are rather simple.

Comment: @SmileyCraft i actually tried to say that subsets would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all I currently know about all eight cases.

Open, closed, continuous: $f(x,y)=(x,y)$

Open, closed, not continuous: Very interesting [A function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ that is open and closed, but not continuous.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3082693/a-function-f-mathbbr2-to-mathbbr2-that-is-open-and-closed-but-not-cont)

Open, not closed, continuous: $f(x,y)=(e^x,y)$

Open, not closed, not continuous: Any [strongly Darboux](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75589/open-maps-which-are-not-continuous) function.

Not open, closed, continuous: $f(x,y)=(0,0)$

Not open, closed, not continuous: $f(x,y)=(\lfloor x\rfloor,0)$

Not open, not closed, continuous: $f(x,y)=(x,0)$

Not open, not closed, not continuous: $f(x,y)=(x+\lfloor x\rfloor,0)$

If you simply want an open, closed function $f:A\to B$ that is not continuous, where $A,B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$, then $f(x,y)=(x-\lfloor x\rfloor,y):\mathbb{R}^2\to\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x\in[0,1)\}$ suffices.

Comment: I don't get the open not closed not continuous case, i was trying for product topology but $sin(x)$ does not take open intervals to open intervals necesseraly, i,e. $sin(A)=[0,2π]$ for some $A$

Comment: Good point. I was already hesitant on my finding. Unfortunately, the simplest example is then probably any strongly Darboux function.

Comment: Don't know It but Will look It up

Answer (score 1):

A constant map is continuous, closed and not open.

Map the closed upper half of the plane to (1,1) and the open lower half to (0,0).
That map is not continuous, closed, not open.

Answer (score 1):

If $f: A\to B$ is a continuous surjection, and $B$ is a subspace of $C,$ and $C$ is a subspace of $D,$ such that  $B$ is not closed in   $C$ and $B$ is not open  in $D,$ then $f:A\to D$ is continuous and $f$ maps $A,$ which is an  open-and-closed subset of $A$(!) onto $B,$ which is neither open nor closed in $D.$

For example $A=\Bbb R^2,\,B= (-\pi/2, \pi/2)\times \{0\},\, C=\Bbb R\times \{0\},$ and $D=\Bbb R^2.$ With $f(x,y)=<\arctan x,\,0>.$

( I am using round brackets $(...,...)$ in the definition of $B$ to  denote an open real interval, and $<...,...>$ in the definition of $f$ to denote an ordered pair.)

Part of the idea is to start with $A,B,$ and $f,$ and look for $C$ such that $B$ is a dense proper subset of $C,$ and $C$ has empty interior in $D$. This is made easier by taking  $1$-dimensional $B$ and $C$, and $D=\Bbb R^2$.