# A function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ that is open and closed, but not continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Does there exist a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ that is open and closed, but not continuous?

Note that I require $f$ to be defined on the entirety of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

There are a few examples of open functions that are not continuous. Most examples I found were functions $f$ with the property that $f(U)=\mathbb{R}^2$ for all open $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$. The extra requirement that $f$ needs to be closed makes things a lot harder, though.

I believe the answer is no, such a function does not exist. My main motivation is the following observation.

**Proposition:** Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be open and closed. If $x_n\to x$ and $f(x_n)$ is bounded, then $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.

*Proof of 1:* Let $f(x_{n_i})$ be a convergent subsequence of $f(x_n)$ with limit $p$. For all $i$ let $y_i=x_{n_i}$ if $f(x_{n_i})\neq p$. Otherwise, let $r=d(x_{n_i},x)$. Then $B_r(x_{n_i})$ is open, so $f(B_r(x_{n_i}))$ is open as well. So $f(B_r(x_{n_i}))\cap B_r(p)\setminus\{p\}$ is not empty. So we can choose $y_i\in B_r(x_{n_i})$ such that $f(y_i)\in B_r(p)\setminus\{p\}$.

We find $y_i\to x$ and $f(y_i)\to p$ and $f(y_i)\neq p$ for all $i$. Let $S=\{y_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$. We find that $p$ is a limit point of $f(S)$ not contained in $f(S)$. However, $C=S\cup\{x\}$ is closed, so $f(C)$ is also closed, and hence contains $p$. We conclude $f(x)=p$, so $f(x_{n_i})\to f(x)$.

Assume for the contrary that $f(x_n)\not\to f(x)$. Then there is a subsequence of $f(x_n)$ that always stays a certain distance from $f(x)$. By the Bolzano Weierstrass theorem, this subsequence itself has a convergent subsequence. By the previous observation, this subsequence converges to $f(x)$. This contradicts the fact that it always stays a certain distance from $f(x)$. $\square$

If you manage to prove that such a function does not exist, it might be neat to also look at how general the domain and codomain of $f$ can be made. For example, all arguments in the proposition still work for $f:X\to Y$ with any metric space $X$, and any finite dimensional vector space $Y$. However, with tweaking the arguments only a bit you find the following.

Let $X$ be a first countable Hausdorff topological space, and let $Y$ be a first countable topological space with no isolated points. Let $f:X\to Y$ be open and closed. If $x_n\to x$ and $f(x_n)$ is contained in some sequentially compact set, then $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.

Anyways, please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: While I'm unsure if it's in the book, one resource for such question is "Counterexamples in Analysis" by Gelbaum and Olmsted.

Comment: @Java, Gelbaum and Olmsted do give a couple of examples of functions that are open and closed but not continuous, but neither one is defined on all of ${\bf R}^2$ with the usual topology.

Comment: @GerryMyerson If one of them is from the reals to the reals, multiply by the identity on a second factor?

Comment: @Henno, one is from the unit circle to a half-open interval. You can extend the domain to be the punctured plane but not (I think) to the whole plane. The other depends on using the discrete topology, rather than the usual topology, on one of the sets.

Comment: This paper may be helpful: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-033-01/S0002-9939-1972-0292041-5/S0002-9939-1972-0292041-5.pdf

Comment: For what it's worth, using your Proposition and the Baire category theorem it is not hard to show that the set of points at which $f$ is continuous must be open and dense.  All my attempts to construct a counterexample have run into obstructions related to winding numbers, so I suspect it's not possible but that a proof will heavily involve special geometric properties of the plane.

Comment: Note in particular that a negative answer would imply a weak form of invariance of domain, namely that every continuous bijection $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is a homeomorphism (otherwise the inverse of such a bijection would be a counterexample).  So, that is a sign that a proof of a negative answer would need to have some serious geometric content.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Interesting paper indeed. They prove any open closed $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Unfortunately, the proof does quite heavily rely on the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is one dimensional. In particular: The boundary of any ball is finite.

Answer (score 10):

I am not sure what happens with the maps of the plane but here is the situation with higher-dimensional domains:

**Theorem 1.** For every $n\ge 3$ there exists a closed and open function $f: R^n\to R^n$ which is not continuous.

**Proof.** While this sounds like a real analysis  theorem, the proof uses some topology.

The key result is a rather nontrivial theorem due to John Walsh (he proved something stronger, I am stating a special case):

**Theorem 2.** Fix $n, m\ge 3$. Then for any pair of compact connected triangulated manifolds (possibly with boundary) $M, N$ of dimensions $m, n$ respectively, every continuous map $g: M\to N$ inducing the surjective map of fundamental groups $\pi_1(M)\to \pi_1(N)$ is homotopic to a (necessarily surjective) open continuous map $h: M\to N$.

See corollary 3.7.2 of

J. Walsh, Monotone and open mappings on manifolds. I. 
Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 209 (1975), 419-432.

This deep theorem is a generalization of earlier results on existence of open continuous dimension-raising maps from $m$-cubes to compact triangulated manifolds due to Keldysh and Wilson.

Now, take $n=m$.

Take $N=T^n$, the $n$-dimensional torus (the $n$-fold product of circles). Fix a triangulation of $N$. Let $M\subset M$ be the complement to the interior of one of the $n$-dimensional simplices in the triangulation of $N$. Take $g: M\to N$ be the identity embedding. Then $g$ induces an isomorphic of fundamental groups (since $n=m\ge 3$). Therefore, by Theorem 2, $g$ is homotopic to a continuous open map $h: M\to N$. The universal covering of $N$ is $p: R^n\to N$; take $X:= p^{-1}(M)$; the restriction of $p$ to $X$ is the universal covering $X\to M$. By the basic covering theory, $h$ lifts to a continuous map $\tilde{h}: X\to R^n$. Since $h$ is homotopic to $g$, the mapping $\tilde{h}$ is properly homotopic to the identity embedding $X\to R^n$, in particular, $\tilde{h}$ is a proper map, hence, a closed map. Since the map $h$ is open, so is the map $\tilde{h}$, where we equip $X$ with the subspace topology induced from $R^n$.

So far, all our maps were continuous, I will now introduce a discontinuity (a very mild one). Each component $C_i$ of $R^n-X$ is an open $n$-dimensional simplex. Therefore, for each $i$ there exists a homeomorphism $c_i: C_i\to R^n$. Now, define the function $f: R^n\to R^n$ whose restriction to $X$ equals $\tilde{h}$ and whose restriction to each $C_i$ equals $c_i$. This function is clearly discontinuous (with discontinuities at the boundaries of the simplices $C_i$).

a. The function $f$ is closed. It suffices to prove that every convergent sequence $x_i\in R^n, x_i\to x$, whose accumulation set in $R^n$ is $\{f(x)\}$. 
After extraction, we can assume that $(x_i)$  either lies in one of the components $C_k$ as above, or it lies in $X$. In the former case, 
$$
\lim_{i\to\infty} f(x_i)= \lim_{i\to\infty} c_k(x_i)=\infty,
$$
so the sequence has no accumulation points in $R^n$. In the latter case, since $X$ is closed, $x\in X$ and since $\tilde{h}$ is continuous, 
$$
\lim_{i\to\infty} f(x_i)= \lim_{i\to\infty} \tilde{h}(x_i)= f(x). 
$$ 
Thus,  $f$ is closed.

b. The function $f$ is open. It suffices to show that every point $x\in R^n$ has a basis of neighborhoods $U$ whose images are open in $R^n$.

b1. The restriction of $f$ to the complement $C= R^n-X$ is  an open map (since each component is mapped homeomorphically to $R^n$). 
Thus, for $x$ in $C$, the claim is clear.

b2. Suppose that $x$ lies in of $X$. Since the mapping $\tilde{h}: X\to R^n$ is open, there is a neighborhood basis $\{U_\alpha\}$ of $x$ in $R^n$ 
 such that $\tilde{h}(U_\alpha)= f(U_\alpha\cap X)$ is open in $R^n$. But $U_\alpha\cap C$ is open, hence, $f(U_\alpha\cap C)$ is open as well (see part b1). Therefore, $f(U_\alpha)$ is open for every $\alpha$. This completes the proof. qed

**Edit.** A better proof is to appeal to the work of David Wilson directly, but you have to dig through his propositions and notation, specifically,

Proposition 3 of

D. Wilson, Open mappings of the universal curve onto continuous curves. 
Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 168 (1972), 497–515.

(this is the real power tool behind all the results)

and

Propositions 1 and 3 of

D. Wilson, Open mappings of the universal curve onto continuous curves. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 168 (1972), 497–515.

Here is what you then get:

**Proposition.** Let $I^n$ be the closed $n$-dimensional cube, $n\ge 3$, and $J^n\subset int(I^n)$ is a closed subcube. Let $Q$ denote the interior of $J^n$. Then, there exists an open continuous map $g: I^n - Q\to I^n$ which equals the identity on the boundary of $I^n$ ends sends $\partial Q$ to the interior of $I^n$.

Given this, proceed as follows. First, extend the map $g$ by identity to the complement of $I^n$ in $R^n$. The result is a proper continuous open map $g: R^n - Q\to R^n$. Extend $g$ to $Q$ by a homeomorphism $Q\to R^n$ (this exists since $Q$ is an open cube). The result is an open and closed discontinuous function $f: R^n\to R^n$, $n\ge 3$. The discontinuity set of $f$ is the boundary of $Q$.

Comment: Who would've thought a simple statement like that can be so deep? :P

Comment: Very interesting answer! I would have never expected to find the answer for $n\geq3$ before finding the answer for $n=2$. Since, strictly speaking, the question in the OP has not been answered, I will not accept the answer. I will give you a bounty for all the work, though!

Comment: Your last proposition  depends on the $g:\Bbb R^n - Q\to \Bbb R^n.$ Is there a reason why there is no such $g$ when $n=2$?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: It is possible that such map exists as well, just the theorems I am quoting require dimension $\ge 3$. I am planning to go through proofs to check if the construction can be adjusted to apply in dimension 2. The quoted theorems also construct open **monotone** maps and the latter will not exist in dimension 2, this follows from a theorem due to Sossinsky. But for what I need, monotonicity is irrelevant.

Comment: @MoisheKohan very nice work. I want to ask though if you think the main problem is true for $n=2$.

Comment: @mathworker21: Yes, I think such examples exist in dimension 2 as well, but proving this would require some serious work.

Comment: Is there a reason you cited Prop. 3 twice? And also silly question: an open map from $I^n \setminus Q \to I^n$ could still send an interior point to the boundary of $I^n$, and then you wouldn’t be able to extend it to a continuous function $\mathbb R^n \setminus Q \to \mathbb R^n$, right?

Comment: @D.R.: There is a number of typos in my answer which need to be cleaned up, referring twice to Prop. 3 is one of these. I would have to think about the proof again to figure out how to deal with the second issue.