# Conditions for continuous map

Tags: general-topology, continuity

today in my topology class we had discussed about continuos map in topological spaces. And I have this question, for $(X,\tau)$ and $(X',\tau')$ two topological spaces and $f\colon X\to X'$, if $f(A)\subseteq X'$ is an open set $\forall A\in\tau$ It implies that $f$ is continuous? or what is necessary to get the continuity of the map?

Comment: The function you're describing is an "open map/function". Open maps need not be continuous.

Answer (score 0):

It is neither necessary nor sufficient for continuity. A function that satisfies this condition is called an “open map”.

For an example of a continuous function that does not satisfy this property, consider the real numbers with the usual topology, and a constant function $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. This is continuous, but the only open set whose direct image is open is the empty set; all other sets have image a singleton, which is not open.

For an example of an open mapping that is not continuous, consider $X=X’=\{a,b\}$, $\tau=\{\varnothing, X\}$, and $\tau’=\{\varnothing, \{a\}, \{b\}, X’\}$. Then the identity map is open, but not continuous. Other examples can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75589/open-maps-which-are-not-continuous).